# How to get Azure Cordova to work with VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Bug with Azure & VS2017 Cordova App

After being pointed to various links by Azure support for a work around.
has anyone got the answer.

**My reply to Azure**

I have read ALL the links and many more.

None of these work.
Upon further investigation, I discover that the issue seems to be that VS2017 has changed the way it works with cordova and the version it uses.

VS2017 Cordova project
[image]
﻿2017 cordova solution  Azure Project
[image]

This is a major issue requiring investigation not a work-around.

Bill

Comment: Hi, Bill - is this a project created from one of the in-product templates, or templates downloaded from the VS Marketplace?

Comment: Yes, was one of the in product templates. Too much of an effort to get working and my customer decided that Azure was not the way forward for them. Now using Sync software with MS SQL and Android.